# Width of bibliography too narrow

Tags: bibliographies, width

I have a problem with my bibliography. The width is too narrow making it look odd. How can I change the width of the bibliography to full width?

Here a summary of my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bbm}
\graphicspath{ {./plots/} }
...
content of the file
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

[image]

EDIT: Hi thanks for the first comments!

In my document I have this towards the end:

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.6\textwidth}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:strategy_explanation}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
Strategy &   Description \\
\midrule
Cell 1 &   Cell 2  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{wraptable}
```

---

Here a compilable version of my code:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bbm}
\graphicspath{ {./plots/} }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\section{Introduction}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.6\textwidth}
\caption{caption}
\label{tab:strategy_explanation}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
Strategy &   Description \\
\midrule
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
Cell 1                &  Cell 2  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{wraptable}

test cite: \cite{Irvin2019}

\pagebreak

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

and here the references.bib

```
@article{Irvin2019,
title = {{CheXpert: A Large Chest Radiograph Dataset with Uncertainty Labels and Expert Comparison}},
year = {2019},
journal = {Proceedings of the AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence},
author = {Irvin, Jeremy and Rajpurkar, Pranav and Ko, Michael and Yu, Yifan and Ciurea-Ilcus, Silviana and Chute, Chris and Marklund, Henrik and Haghgoo, Behzad and Ball, Robyn and Shpanskaya, Katie and Seekins, Jayne and Mong, David A. and Halabi, Safwan S. and Sandberg, Jesse K. and Jones, Ricky and Larson, David B. and Langlotz, Curtis P. and Patel, Bhavik N. and Lungren, Matthew P. and Ng, Andrew Y.},
month = {1},
pages = {590--597},
volume = {33},
url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07031 http://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07031},
doi = {10.1609/aaai.v33i01.3301590},
issn = {2159-5399},
arxivId = {1901.07031}
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Please give us an short compilable tex code resulting in your shown screenshot, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: It appears that somewhere in the article you have switched to two-column, but nothing you show indicates anything obvious.  It might be possible that you have input a very long `\wrapfigure` near the ens of the previous page.  All this is only a guess, and my crystal ball has gone murky.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I have a wraptable. How do I make sure it doesn't affect the bibliography? Can I reset the width?

Comment: With a wrapped table or figure, the significant dimension affecting the narrowing going on too far is the length, not the width.  So resetting the width, unless it makes the table occupy less vertical space, isn't going to make any difference.  I see there's now an example.  If it produces the described problem, then it should be able to diagnose it and propose a fix.  (I can't do that right now, but will come back to see if anyone has taken up the challenge.)

Comment: It just occurred to me ... bibliographies are implemented as lists.  That is the very worst situation with respect to wrapfigure -- documented to be incompatible, or at least problematic.  A fix will have to take that into consideration.

Comment: With the example provided, changing `\pagebreak` to `\clearpage` restored. the page to full width for the bibliography.  I haven't looked up the definitions of the two page breaking commands, so I can consider this approach only a hack at the moment.  But, at the cost of forcing the bibliography to always start on a new page, this should rescue your project.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes that works. Thank you so much! (If you copy your comment as an answer I can mark it as solved for future users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that a bibliography is defined as a list, and just preceding the bibliography is a "wrapped" table, entered using `\wraptable` from the `wrapfigure` package.  The effect was to reduce the width available for setting the bibliography entries to what was appropriate for the narrow column to the left of the table.

The `wrapfigure` package is documented to be incompatible with any list environment.

An attempt was made to break the unwanted association by inserting `\newpage`, but that didn't have the desired effect.  Replacing that with `\clearpage` did have the desired result, restoring the full page width for use by the bibliography.

What is the difference between `\newpage` and `\clearpage` that makes this happen?  In addition to proceeding to a new page, `\clearpage` forces all pending floats to be resolved before proceeding.  Among other things, this restores the page width to its normal value.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate your help!